# Spacing by a calculated value with a counter

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, counters, calc

I want to create an oblique table of content, my strategy has been so far to do the following:

```
\newcounter{agendacount}
\setcounter{agendacount}{0}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
    \hspace{-0.1\theagendacount\paperwidth}
    \inserttocsection
    \addtocounter{agendacount}{1}
}
```

The problem is `hspace` doesn't seem to work like that, I do get an oblique toc, but it's not calculated with my value, if I replace `-0.1` by `-0.09`, everything is broken

How can I use `hspace` with a spacing value that is calculated using a counter ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

[image: x]

You can use the package `calc` to multiply the entries offset `\agendashift`  (a length) by   `agendacount` (a number).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{default}

% *********************************************** added 
\newcounter{agendacount}
\setcounter{agendacount}{1}
\newlength{\agendashift}

\usepackage{calc}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\setlength{\agendashift}{20pt} % added horizontal offset of ToC entries <<<

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
\hspace*{\the\agendashift*\theagendacount}\inserttocsection%     
\stepcounter{agendacount}
}
%********************************************

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{First day}
    \section{First day}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Second day}
    \section{Second day}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Third day}
    \section{Third day}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Fourth day}
    \section{Fourth day}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank, it looks like exactly what I need, but somehow, when I try it it doesn't work.
It also doesn't make a table of content with your example, I have to put \section before the frame for it to work

Comment: @BlueMagma Run exactly my example with a new name. It must be compiled twice to show the ToC.  Just in case I am using   `beamer.cls    2021/03/19 v3.62 `

Comment: What I meant to say: When I use exactly your example in a new file, it doesn't do the shifting, I get '*1', '*2' in front of the the toc entry. I must be missing a package or dependancy or something